# Issue with Laravel Excel When Importing Excel Files on Online Server - Zip Member Not Found

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import, server

I am encountering an issue when trying to import an Excel file using Laravel Excel in my Laravel application. I have used the following code to upload and import the file:

```
public function import_excel(Request $request) 
{
    try {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
        ]);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($e->validator->errors())->withInput();
    }

    // capturing the excel file
    $file = $request->file('file');

    // creating a unique file name
    $nama_file = rand().$file->getClientOriginalName();

    $file->move('file_member', $nama_file);

    // importing data
    Excel::import(new MemberImport, public_path('/file_member/' . $nama_file));

    // notifying through session
    $message = [
        "status" => $file ? "success" : "failed",
        "message" => $file ? "Member Data Successfully Imported" : "Failed to Import Member Data!"
    ];

    // redirecting back
    return redirect()->route('index.member.registration')->with("message", $message);
}
```

However, when attempting to import the file in the production environment, I encountered the error
"Could not find zip member zip:///home/u1572391/public_html/koperasi-app/storage/framework/cache/laravel-excel/laravel-excel-wVFjYv63g1d69UTbCrnD9xb7WAc37Hse.xlsx#_rels.rels,"

indicating an issue with finding a specific member within the zip file. Can anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to handle this error? Are there any additional configurations or steps that need to be taken in the production environment?

when I tried to import on my local site it went well but when I tried it on the online server, I got the error

Comment: php-zip extension is installed on the server ?

Comment: I didn't install it on the server, cause I didn't think it was necessary

Comment: check it if is installed and if not install it and then check if the error persists

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates an xlsx file that cannot be read

You can provide your xlsx file if you would like a more accurate answer

The 4 most likely culprits are:

1. Your file is password protected (in which case it cannot be read), so remove the password and reupload
2. Your uploaded file has an invalid extension (for instance it's an xls or csv file but the extension was manually set to xlsx)
3. You have file permission issues in your storage directory, or a missing storage directory, maybe because of an incorrect umask or you forgot to run `php artisan storage:link`, check the permissions of the file `app/storage/framework/cache/laravel-excel/laravel-excel-wVFjYv63g1d69UTbCrnD9xb7WAc37Hse.xlsx`
4. You are missing a required php extension (If you are using composer correctly it should have errored when you ran `composer install`) [Here is the list of required php extensions](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/composer.json#L69-L81C25)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After attempting to change the file destination to the storage, it was successfully saved after I created a symbolic link to the storage.